# How to implements facebook comments plugin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

how to implements facebook comments plugin in our website?

i'm following this code for showing the comments, but why the comments plugin still not showing?

inside tag body, i'm put this code :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/id_ID/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=<client-id>&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and in my page, i'm put this code :

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

why still not showing?

Comment: does your website run on any cms or its a custom made one? share th url of the website where you've implemented the above code.

Comment: you've replaced the app ID with your app id in the above code as well?

Comment: yes, i'm replace my app-id inside <client-id> in yhe above code

Comment: can you show it on your website right now? will have to see there wats wrong

Comment: I am assuming that you would've changed the data-href also to your current website url/page 
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<website-url>" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>